# Auto resize a <object> according to document

Tags: html, css

I have a word document saved as an HTML file, and when I try to embed it, it seems like everything I try to do, I cant get it to resize according to the text, and what I mean by this is I want the height of the embedding to be 100% or you know what I mean, I just want it to cover the page without it hiding anything of my text.

Comment: nope, don't know what you mean. Embed your html into what? Examples/snapshots help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the width attributes in terms of percentage.
for example:
`<pre width='80%'>content</pre>`.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: I cant see were this is helping me? How should the pre tag help me when im using an object tag?

Comment: try this with object tag

Comment: try to add this property with object tag overflow: scroll;

Comment: But if i add this then i should scroll down the page right, but i want it to fully cover the heigth.

Comment: try setting height='100vp' or height='800px'.percentage wont work with height.

Comment: I tried to use object tag with word document.But it simply doesn't work.If you can convert  the word document in to a pdf, then you can use <iframe> tag.It will be much easier.                                        <iframe width='100%' height='600px' src="b.pdf"></iframe>

Comment: But if i make it into a pdf and use i frame does i not use flash then and qill ask to run?

Comment: Oh, and when using object tag, the word documwnt is saved in html document